# Magento Shortcode CMS block not working on product pages

Tags: magento, block

I am attempting to add a CMS block on a Magento product page.

The shortcode which I am using is:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="myproductblock"}}
```

The block shows up as text.  It does not insert the CMS block.  I have made sure that the WYSIWYG editor is disabled.

Comment: Out of my head, I think you have to write `{{block id="myproductblock"}}`

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to add it to product.phtml

To do this, you need to edit the layout/catalog.xml

```
...
<catalog_product_view>
..
...
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
    <!-- start your code: -->
    <block type="cms/block" name="myproductblock" before="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>myproductblock</block_id></action>
    </block>
```

Then inside your view.phtml you write:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("myproductblock") ?>
```

Where the "myproductblock" is the same as the name you specified inside the layout.xml

After this you have to clear the layout.xml cache and it should work :)

---

Why your code didn't work:
Those .phtml files all are php-scripts.. the "{{" and "}}" must interpreted by a template engine and is only valid inside emails, CMS pages/blocks and the wysiwyg editors in the backend.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Based upon your answers it would seem that I could only display 1 named block on product pages.  Is there a way to define the block name on the product page,  for example if I want to have different block names for different products.

Comment: You can also circumvent to edit the layout.xml with following code:

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('myproductblock')->toHtml() ?> 

So it would work if you do this:

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product_'.$_product->getSku())->toHtml() ?> 

Then if you want a specific block for product with sku=123 you add in backend "product_123" as blockid.

I hope this helps :)

PS: sorry for the formatting - I think one shouldn't add code in comments^^